# Trouble with getting a returned value from a function

Tags: javascript, html, function

Below is a small snippet of my project, I had these functions working one in one but when I modified other functions to my program the code below stopped working.

What I am trying to do is get an input from the user (ex Jan) one of the labels in the array of objects daysInMonth, then from that return the value of the object along with the index of that object in the array.

My problem is when I call getMonthNum() inside of DrawCal() to get the value of returnMonDayNum returns 0 even though inside the getMonthNum function it returns 31, if you use Jan as an example.

```js
var daysInMonth = [{
    label: 'Jan',
    value: 31
  }, {
    label: 'Feb',
    value: 28
  }, {
    label: 'Marc',
    value: 31
  }, {
    label: 'Apr',
    value: 30
  },
  {
    label: 'May',
    value: 31
  }, {
    label: 'June',
    value: 30
  }, {
    label: 'July',
    value: 31
  }, {
    label: 'Aug',
    value: 31
  },
  {
    label: 'Sept',
    value: 30
  }, {
    label: 'Oct',
    value: 31
  }, {
    label: 'Nov',
    value: 30
  }, {
    label: 'Dec',
    value: 31
  }
]


function getMonthNum() {

  var monInput = document.getElementById("month").value;

  for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    if (daysInMonth[i].label == monInput) {
      var returnMonDayNum = daysInMonth[i].value;
      var returnMonNum = i;
      console.log(monInput);
      console.log(returnMonDayNum);
      console.log(i);
      return returnMonDayNum, returnMonNum;
    }
  }
}


function DrawCal() {

  var returnMonDayNum = getMonthNum(returnMonDayNum);
  console.log(returnMonDayNum);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="DrawCal();">
  <label>Month: <input type="text" name="Enter Month" id="month" required></label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="MakeCal">
</form>
```

Comment: `return returnMonDayNum,returnMonNum`

Comment: @Amit I'm not sure if you just changed the layout of edited something within the code but I still don't get 31 inside the DrawCal() function

Comment: I'm just pointing you in the direction of your mistake. You probably should spend some time learning JavaScript if that doesn't mean much to you. Good luck :-)

Comment: @Amit yeah I'm new to JavaScript I didn't know you couldn't return more than one var now I know, I was just confused with your comment because it was just highlighted. Sorry I didn't know you meant that's where the issue lied. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to return two things from `getMonthNum`. If you really want to return both the index and number of days, you should put them in an array. Otherwise you'll just get the last one in the list.

Then you can reference which item you want in the array.

As a side note, you might find array functions like [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) a little nicer than `for` loops for things like this.
(I've also added stopDefault(), just to prevent the form from refreshing so the results stay in the console — that may not be what you want in your actual code).

```js
var daysInMonth = [{label: 'Jan',value: 31}, {label: 'Feb',value: 28}, {label: 'Marc',value: 31}, {label: 'Apr',value: 30},{label: 'May',value: 31}, {label: 'June',value: 30}, {label: 'July',value: 31}, {label: 'Aug',value: 31},{label: 'Sept',value: 30}, {label: 'Oct',value: 31}, {label: 'Nov',value: 30}, {label: 'Dec',value: 31}]

function getMonthNum() {

  var monInput = document.getElementById("month").value;

  for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    if (daysInMonth[i].label == monInput) {
      var returnMonDayNum = daysInMonth[i].value;
      var returnMonNum = i;
      console.log("input:", monInput);
      console.log("days:",returnMonDayNum);
      console.log("i:",i);
      return [returnMonDayNum, returnMonNum];
    }
  }
}


function DrawCal(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var result = getMonthNum();
  // result is an array: [returnMonDayNum, returnMonNum]
  console.log("days:", result[0]);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="DrawCal(event);">
  <label>Month: <input type="text" name="Enter Month" id="month" required></label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="MakeCal">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you thought I could return 2 at the same time

Answer (score 1):

```js
var daysInMonth = [{
    label: 'Jan',
    value: 31
  }, {
    label: 'Feb',
    value: 28
  }, {
    label: 'Marc',
    value: 31
  }, {
    label: 'Apr',
    value: 30
  },
  {
    label: 'May',
    value: 31
  }, {
    label: 'June',
    value: 30
  }, {
    label: 'July',
    value: 31
  }, {
    label: 'Aug',
    value: 31
  },
  {
    label: 'Sept',
    value: 30
  }, {
    label: 'Oct',
    value: 31
  }, {
    label: 'Nov',
    value: 30
  }, {
    label: 'Dec',
    value: 31
  }
]


function getMonthNum() {

  var monInput = document.getElementById("month").value;

  var returnMonDayNum
  var returnMonNum

  for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    if (daysInMonth[i].label === monInput) {
      returnMonDayNum = daysInMonth[i].value;
      returnMonNum = i;
    }
  }
  return `Month: ${returnMonNum}. Days in ${daysInMonth[returnMonNum].label}: ${returnMonDayNum}`
}


function DrawCal() {

  console.log(getMonthNum());
}

document.querySelector('.submit').addEventListener('click', DrawCal)
```

```html
<label>Month: <input type="text" name="Enter Month" id="month" required></label>

<button class="submit" value="MakeCal">Submit</button>
```